# laravel get entries of last month, displaying them day by day

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, php-carbon

What's the best way to get all records from the last month, day by day using the default laravel "created_at" as timestamp of creation.

Is there some way to prevent needless database load, when loading them?

database design is laravel "basic"

```
id|name|created_at|updated_at
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this [article](http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/) regarding date filtering.

```
$q->whereDay('created_at', '=', date('d'));
$q->whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('m'));
$q->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'));
```